# Question about installing Signal Processing Toolbox in Matlab

Tags: matlab

So, i found a gspbox on Github and downloaded the zip file, then compiled. On matlab I ran the following commands: gsp_start, gsp_make and then gsp_install. When executing the last command I got a Warning: "Could not install GAIMC" and when I tried to use a function mscohere it didn't allow me to saying that I need a Signal Processing Toolbox. I was wondering whether the gspbox is something different from the Signal processing toolbox or maybe the warning about the uninstalled GAIMC causes the problem?

Comment: “A gspbox”? Maybe you mean this toolbox? https://epfl-lts2.github.io/gspbox-html/ If so, please include the link in your question, it’s not like everybody knows what that is.

Comment: If you get that error message, it likely means that the toolbox requires the Signal Processing Toolbox. This is one of the standard MATLAB toolboxes. Since the software you’re trying to run is academic, I’m not surprised that they don’t bother listing it as a prerequisite, Universities tend to have access to all toolboxes and those people often don’t realize they’re using functionality from a toolbox.

Comment: mscohere is actually part of the signal processing toolbox. Why do you install one toolbox to then call a function from a different toolbox? And yes, both are different.